# How do I pass a variable through multiple inner functions in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a function `peg`:

```
  peg: {{$[abs[log x%y]>0.06;y;x]} scan x}
```

The `0.06` is a parameter that I'd like to pass to `peg` from the outside, so I can do something like `0.06 peg x`.

What's a clean way of passing this variable through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the function to add explicit variables so you can keep the local variable names as `x` and `y`. Below I've added a new argument `v` for the value you want to pass.

```
peg: {[v;x]{[v;x;y]$[abs[log x%y]>v;y;x]}[v] scan x}

peg[0.06;x]
```

I don't think there's any other easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Only inbuilt operators and keywords can use infix notation:

```
x func y
```

User defined functions must use bracket notation

```
func[x;y]
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#prefix-infix-postfix
- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#bracket-notation

You can use projection to pass in arguments.
kdb will autodetect implicit arguments `[x;y;z]`

```
peg:{{$[abs[log y%z]>x;z;y]}[x] scan y}
```

For readability would suggest to choose your own names though:

```
peg:{[lim;lis] 
      {[lim;pre;cur] 
        $[abs[log pre%cur]>lim;cur;pre]}[lim] scan lis
     }
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/application/#projection
- https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#617-implicit-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You pass it through by adding an extra variable to your inner function like Thomas showed, and passing the variable into that.

To answer your second part of calling it `0.06 peg x` ... you can really only use this "infix" notation for built-in functions although you can hack it by defining your function in the q namespace

```
q).q.peg:{{$[abs[log y%z]>x;z;y]}[x]scan y}
q)0.6 peg 1 2 3 4
1 2 2 4
```

Not recommended to mess with the .q namespace though so not worth the hassle

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines:

```
peg:{{$[abs[log x%y]>z;y;x]}[;;y]\[x]}
```

So if you define like:

```
v:(1;1.05;1.03;1.1;1;1.04)
```

Running `peg[v;0.06]` you'll get:

```
1 1 1 1.1 1 1
```